# Does the Learning App IOS documentation still work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I want to use the steps outlined here: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/LearningAppIos/#0002

The goal is to create an app that I can test MobilePush notifications. The Learning App IOS doc is the only resource I found on the topic of creating something for a testing environment. Does this still work and/or are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@McdonaldZip, if you look at the main GitHub page for that version the LearningApp (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppIos) you'll see we've rewritten and replaced with a more clear, consistent and supportable sample.

See https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/master/LearningApp for all the details. The LearningApp will be maintained alongside our SDK directly.

Comment: thanks, I will refer to the latest version.